# SQL customer who never order product p1 and p2 together

Tags: sql

I do have two table. I want to find customers who never order product p1 and p2 together(there are million rows in this table)

```
customer_id  2,4,1,4,2,1,3,2,1   

product_id.  p1,p3,p2,p1,p2,p3,p4,p2
```

Comment: what's your definition of together, same date or time? Also provide test data in tabular format.

Comment: Is it MySQL or PostgreSQL? Those are two very different animals.

Comment: @zealous, that was an interview question. There is a one table which name is customer_orders. and there is a two column customer_id and product _id. It was asked that tell me the customers who never order product p1 and p2 in the same order together. following question was to tell me customers never order consecutively. that was the all info no extra info provided to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, with your *very limited information*, here is the solution. I broke it up to pieces, for you to understand it better

```
-- to get customers who ordered P1 
Select customer_id from tbl where product_id = 'P1'

-- to get customers who ordered P2
Select customer_id from tbl where product_id = 'P2'

-- to get customers who ordered both P1 & P2
Select customer_id from tbl p1 
inner join tbl p2 on p1.customer_id = p2.customer_id 
where p1.product_id = 'P1' and p2.product_id = 'P2'

-- to get customers who did not ordered both P1 & P2 together
Select * from tbl m
Left Join
(
Select customer_id from tbl p1 
inner join tbl p2 on p1.customer_id = p2.customer_id 
where p1.product_id = 'P1' and p2.product_id = 'P2'
) q on m.customer_id = q.customer_id
Where q.customer_id is null
```

Comment: If you can tell the Database, and provide with some sample data and expected output, it would be much easier. it shouldn't be totally different tables. in that case there is no way to know who made what order

Comment: Hi Srinika, Thanks a lot. this solution gave me a great idea how to approach to question.if the statement was consecutively p1 and p2 product in the same order instead of together  p1 and p2 product in the same order. answer would be the same?

Comment: @Berk Yünür, its hard to answer further, as the info is insufficient.

Comment: This is only one table. My mistake, there are two columns which are customer_id and product_id. as I stated above
 customer_id  2,4,1,4,2,1,3,2,1   
product_id.  p1,p3,p2,p1,p2,p3,p4,p2 I need to find the customer_id who never order  p1 and p2 consecutively in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one table with customer ids and product ids, then you can use aggregation:

```
select customer_id
from t
group by customer_id
having sum(case when product_id = 'P1' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 or
       sum(case when product_id = 'P2' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

That is, get customer who have not ordered one of the products.

Note that "ordered together" implies that they are in the same order.  However, you data does not provide any information about orders or the timing of purchases.

Comment: Hi Gardon, you are right there is on table and  two column. What I wanted ask is that customer_id who give orders never give the p1 and p2 product together in the same order. Do you think that if the statement changes as never give the p1 and p2 product 'consecutively' , answer would be different?

Comment: @BerkYünür . . . This returns customers who have never purchased both products -- which given the sample data in your question is the best that can be done.

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

the answer for this question if i understood it correctly that you want to find customers who have ordered p1 but never p2 and have ordered p2 but never p1.

```
Select b.customerid, b.productid 
Table1 b 
inner join 
(Select customerid, count(distinct productid) 
From table1
Where productid in (‘P1’, ‘P2’)
group by
Customerid
Having
count(distinct productid) = 1) a 
on (b.customerid = a.customerid)
And  b.productid in (‘P1’, ‘P2’)
```